# Yii CDbCriteria compare get all values

Tags: php, yii, criteria

basically what im trying to do here is to get posts based on a certain field,i've used a for each for that,after that i want to get all other posts .How do i do it?

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
            'order'=>'create_time,likes DESC',
                ));

                foreach ($str_priority as $key=>$val) {
                    if($key!="") 
                    $criteria->compare('tag',$key,true,'OR',true);

                }
                    $criteria->compare('tag',"",true,'OR',true);


            $total = Post::model()->count();
            $pages = new CPagination($total);
            $pages->pageSize = 10;
            $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
            $posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: other post means records which doesn't meet your condition?

Comment: @kumar_v yes posts which fail the condition

Answer (score 0):

you can try such this
`$criteria->addInCondition('tag', $str_priority, 'OR');`